# Can I create a View of Function from a Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can I create a view or function using the below query?  It uses temp tables.  I am not able to create either a view or function.

```
    --TEmp table--
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Enquiries') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Enquiries
        GO
        CREATE TABLE #Enquiries
        (ID INT,PID INT,Name VARCHAR(50),Enquiries INT,EnquiryDate datetime)
        INSERT INTO #Enquiries
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (ORDER BY ProjectName) AS Row, (SELECT top 1 ITEM FROM DBO.split(e.InterestedProjects,',')) as Projects,P.ProjectName,COUNT(CAST(EnquiryDate AS DATE)) AS Enquiries,CAST(EnquiryDate AS DATE) AS EnquiryDate
        FROM tbl_Enquiry e INNER JOIN   
        tbl_Projects AS P ON P.ProjectId = (SELECT TOP 1 ITEM FROM DBO.split(e.InterestedProjects,',')) 
        WHERE e.IsActive=1 and e.isdeleted=0 AND p.IsActive=1 AND p.IsDeleted=0 AND P.ProjectId IN (SELECT TOP 1 ITEM FROM DBO.split(e.InterestedProjects,','))
        GROUP BY e.InterestedProjects,P.ProjectName,CAST(EnquiryDate AS DATE)
        --SiteVisits
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SiteVisit') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #SiteVisit
        GO
        CREATE TABLE #SiteVisit
        (ID INT,PID INT,Name VARCHAR(50),Sitevisits INT,PickUpDatetime datetime)
        INSERT INTO #SiteVisit
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProjectName) AS Row,s.ProjectId,p.ProjectName As Name,count(sd.PickUpDatetime) AS Sitevisits,CAST(PickUpDatetime AS DATE) AS PickUpDatetime FROM tbl_SiteVisit s
        INNER JOIN tbl_SiteVisitDetails sd ON s.SiteVisitId=sd.SiteVisitId
        INNER JOIN tbl_Projects p ON p.ProjectId=s.ProjectId
        WHERE s.IsActive=1 and s.isdeleted=0 AND sd.isactive=1 AND sd.isdeleted=0 
        GROUP BY s.ProjectId,sd.PickUpDatetime,p.ProjectName,CAST(PickUpDatetime AS DATE)
        --Bookings
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Bookings') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE #Bookings
        GO
        CREATE TABLE #Bookings
        (ID INT,PID INT,Name VARCHAR(50),Bookings INT,BookingDate datetime,Revenue money,Area float)
        INSERT INTO #Bookings
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProjectName) AS Row, u.ProjectId AS ProjectId,p.ProjectName,count(u.ProjectId) AS Bookings,CAST(b.BookingDate AS DATE) AS BookingDate,SUM(b.TotalAmount) AS [Revenue],SUM(u.UnitArea) AS [Area] FROM tbl_Bookings b
        INNER JOIN tbl_Unit u ON b.UnitId=u.UnitId
        INNER JOIN tbl_Projects p on p.ProjectId=u.ProjectId
        WHERE b.IsActive=1 AND b.IsDeleted=0 and u.IsActive=1 AND u.IsDeleted=0 AND u.Status = 'B'
        GROUP BY u.ProjectId,p.ProjectName,CAST(b.BookingDate AS DATE),b.TotalAmount,u.UnitArea
        --ORDER BY u.ProjectId

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T1') IS NOT NULL                                                                            
        DROP TABLE #T1                                                                       
        create TABLE #T1 (  
        PrimaryNo INT,                                                           
        EnquiryDate Date,
        Enquiries INT,
        SiteVisits INT,
        Bookings INT,
        Revenue Money,
        Area Float,
        PID INT,
        ProjectName nvarchar(max)
        ) 
        INSERT INTO #T1(PrimaryNo,EnquiryDate,Enquiries,PID,ProjectName)

        SELECT ID,EnquiryDate,sum(enquiries) AS Enquiries,PID,Name FROM #Enquiries GROUP BY id,pid,Name,enquirydate

            DECLARE @SVDate date                      
            DECLARE @SV11 INT 
            DECLARE @BookingDate Date      
            DECLARE @Bookings11 INT       
            DECLARE @Revenue11 MONEY    
            DECLARE @Area11 FLOAT   

            DECLARE @intFlag_pw11 INT                      
            SET @intFlag_pw11 = 1                      
            DECLARE @TableCntw11 INT    

            DECLARE @Date Date                  
            DECLARE Cur_SiteVisit CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR                

            SELECT PickUpDatetime FROM #SiteVisit

           OPEN Cur_SiteVisit                      
           FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_SiteVisit INTO @Date                      

           DECLARE @ProjectId INT  
           DECLARE @Count INT = 1

           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0                      
           BEGIN                        
              SET @ProjectId = (SELECT PID FROM #SiteVisit WHERE ID = @Count)  

              SET @SVDate = ISNULL((SELECT CAST(PickUpDatetime AS DATE) FROM #SiteVisit
                                    WHERE CAST(PickUpDatetime AS DATE) = @Date AND PID = @ProjectId
                                    GROUP BY PickUpDatetime),'-')

              SET @SV11 = ISNULL((SELECT Sitevisits FROM #SiteVisit
                                    WHERE CAST(PickUpDatetime AS DATE) = @Date AND PID = @ProjectId
                                    GROUP BY Sitevisits),0)                               

                EXEC ('UPDATE #T1 SET SiteVisits = ' + @SV11 + ' WHERE EnquiryDate = ' + ''''+  @SVDate +''' AND PID =' +  @ProjectId)    

             FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_SiteVisit INTO @Date      
             SET @Count = @Count + 1               
               END      

            CLOSE Cur_SiteVisit                      
            DEALLOCATE Cur_SiteVisit                           

           --For Bookings
            DECLARE @Date1 Date                  
            DECLARE Cur_Bookings CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR     

            SELECT BookingDate FROM #Bookings 

           OPEN Cur_Bookings                      
           FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Bookings INTO @Date1                      

           DECLARE @ProjectId1 INT  
           DECLARE @Count1 INT = 1

           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0                      
           BEGIN            

              SET @ProjectId1 = (SELECT PID FROM #Bookings WHERE ID = @Count1)  

              SET @Bookings11 = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1  Bookings FROM #Bookings
                                    WHERE CAST(BookingDate AS DATE) = @Date1 AND PID = @ProjectId1
                                    GROUP BY Bookings),0) 

              SET @BookingDate = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1  CAST(BookingDate AS DATE) FROM #Bookings
                                    WHERE CAST(BookingDate AS DATE) = @Date1 AND PID = @ProjectId1
                                    GROUP BY CAST(BookingDate AS DATE)),'-')      

            SET @Revenue11 =    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Revenue FROM #Bookings
                                    WHERE CAST(BookingDate AS DATE) = @Date1 AND PID = @ProjectId1
                                    GROUP BY Revenue),0)        

            SET @Area11 =    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Area FROM #Bookings
                                    WHERE CAST(BookingDate AS DATE) = @Date1 AND PID = @ProjectId1
                                    GROUP BY Area),0)  
              EXEC ('UPDATE #T1 SET Bookings = ' + @Bookings11 + ',Revenue=' + @Revenue11 + ',Area = ' + @Area11 + ' WHERE EnquiryDate = ' + '''' +  @BookingDate + ''' AND PID =' +  @ProjectId1)    

             FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_Bookings INTO @Date1 
              SET @Count1 = @Count1 + 1 

               END      

            CLOSE Cur_Bookings                      
            DEALLOCATE Cur_Bookings

        Select * from #T1
```

Comment: [User-Defined Functions That Return a table Data Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214485(v=sql.80).aspx) example here on SO [My first table valued function and cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400842/my-first-table-valued-function-and-cursor)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a view from that, if only because you're doing a number of inserts and other actions.  A view is created from a single query.

With regard to user-defined functions:  you cannot use dynamic SQL, which you are doing:

```
EXEC ('UPDATE #T1 SET Bookings = ' + @Bookings11 + ',Revenue=' + @Revenue11 + 
    ',Area = ' + @Area11 + ' WHERE EnquiryDate = ' + '''' +  @BookingDate + 
    ''' AND PID =' +  @ProjectId1)
```

You also can't use temp tables.  Both of these limitations are documented here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx.

But, you can do all of these things in a stored procedure.  It is also possible to direct the output of a stored procedure to a temp table or table variable, allowing you to use the output in another query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
(MyTableId, Column1, Column2) -- arbitrary-chosen column names
EXEC  dbo.MyStoredProcedure 

SELECT *
FROM   dbo.MyTable 
WHERE  Column1 = 'Some Value'
```

Finally, you might be able to rework your SQL to work with table variables rather than temp tables, which are allowed.  It also looked to me like your dynamic SQL didn't need to be dynamic, so you might be able to eliminate that as well.

Hope this helps.